# Are all system calls non-realtime-safe?

Tags: linux, real-time, system-calls

I've heard that executing system calls in Linux (RT_PREEMPT kernel) is never realtime-safe.

This seems overly-restrictive -- how could your process do anything (unless it has to be done entirely through DMA) without system calls?

Is this true, or are some system calls (like clock_gettime) realtime-safe?

Comment: What is **your** ***exact** definition* of *"realtime-safety"* ?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, a realtime-safe operation will always complete or fail within a reasonably small time. We're trying to run a control loop a 1 kHz... obviously, we need to avoid FS and many other operations, but do we need too avoid *all* system call to guarantee an execution time < 1 ms?

Comment: What do you mean by "guaranteeing an execution time" less than a millisecond. Does your life depend on that promise???? I'll bet that a well coded realtime program on a well configured Linux RT_PREEMPT kernel & system with a fast-enough hardware would meet that deadline; but you have to decide if my feeling is enough.

Comment: With our new system, exceeding 2ms (total for all threads, not just for one call) in one loop will cause a hardware-based shutdown of our robot. We do tend to meet our deadlines... but I've heard that system calls aren't realtime-safe, and don't understand why.

Comment: Some system calls might require scheduling of non-real time kernel threads, but that is probably weird. Details are system specific (e.g. consider when ELF binaries are on a network file system...). I'll guess that with appropriate care (notably at the sysadmin level) that won't happen.

Comment: Guess or guarantee? 99.999% of the time, we do not see large latencies (yes, that is the right number of nines for the testing we've done). I guess that the system calls we use are realtime-safe... but I've heard that this isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @crosstalk That's right linux, even with the realtime extensions, is not a hard realtime system, execution time is not guaranteed. You need another operating system for that, e.g. vxworks or qnx.

Comment: More importantly, Linux being a GPLv2 free software, there is no warranty attached, so I suppose that nothing is guaranteed. However, you have the source code and an amazing kernel developer community to help you forge your own opinion. (and I'm not sure that *VxWorks* or *Qnx* gives you a legally binding guarantee....)

Comment: nos: Do you know why that is?
Basile: I've thought about looking through the kernel... but it's kinda big ;) However, I guess a post to the LKML wouldn't be unwarranted...

Comment: Why would sched_getaffinity(), looking for the affinity of a realtime process, possibly block? The scheduler clearly needs to access that info in a realtime manner... why can't the system call do so?

Answer (score 1):

If by "realtime safe" you mean guaranteed to execute within a bounded time, then linux, like most general-purpose operating systems, is not realtime safe.

Various [real-time operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) (RTOS) provided this kind of guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at the file `functions` from the `jack_interposer` repository. These are *not* real-time safe. It is an easer question than asking which *are* real-time safe. A good rule of thumb for what should be avoided are:

- Any blocking synchronization function
- Any memory allocation function
- Any I/O function
- Algorithms (within user-space) that have a complexity greater than O(n), where n is the number of elements in the input buffer.